# use select menu to show some table in form

Tags: javascript, html

I use select menu to show some of the table in my form but it doesn't show the table if I want to display it.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td><select id="add" onchange="disablefield(this)" >
<option value="00">select</option>
<option value="a" >Name 1</option>
<option value="b" >Name 2</option>
<option value="c" >Name 3</option>
</select>
</tr></td>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr style ="display:none;" id="name11"><td><input type="text" style="width:100%;background:#FAB89B;border:0;line-height: 20px;padding: 5px;"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr style ="display:none;"id="name12"><td><input type="text" style="width:100%;background:#FAB89B;border:0;line-height: 20px;padding: 5px;"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr style ="display:none;"id="name13"><td><input type="text" style="width:100%;background:#FAB89B;border:0;line-height: 20px;padding: 5px;"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function disablefield(e)
    {
        if (e == "a"){
            document.getElementById('name11').style.display = '';
else if (e == "b"){
                document.getElementById('name12').style.display = '';
else if (e == "c"){
                document.getElementById('name13').style.display = '';
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you create Jsfiddle and add it in here?

Comment: Your missing some brackets with the if statements as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function disablefield (select) {
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedOption == "a"){
        document.getElementById('name11').style.display = '';
    }
    else if (selectedOption == "b"){
        document.getElementById('name12').style.display = '';
    }
    else if (selectedOption == "c"){
        document.getElementById('name13').style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Than you can just leave the onchange="disablefield(this)" in your HTML.

You can see it work here: https://jsfiddle.net/pjdrfz8g/

Comment: Could you please mark any of the right answers as the right answer, than this question is solved. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the value not the element itself since you have passed the element to function `disablefield(this)`. So, instead of

```
if (e == ...
```

it should be

```
 if (e.value == ...
```

and also close your `if` statement properly

```
if (e.value == "a"){
    document.getElementById('name11').style.display = '';
}
else if (e.value == "b"){
    document.getElementById('name12').style.display = '';
}
else if (e.value == "c"){
    document.getElementById('name13').style.display = '';
}
```

Comment: I Write in Xcode it not have console  this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgur9j75/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgur9j75/3/

The problem was with

-- e=='a' , Sol: e.value='a'
-- Missing Closing braces for if else ladder

```
function disablefield(e)
    {
        if (e.value == 'a')
            document.getElementById('name11').style.display = 'block';
        else if (e.value == 'b')
                document.getElementById('name12').style.display = '';
        else if (e.value == 'c')
                document.getElementById('name13').style.display = '';
    }
```